# rails 4 validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a custom validation in a Rails 4 app. It's simply a user form that should submit the user's domain name, which is then validated to make sure the site exists.

The validations look like this:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :domain, presence: true
validate :domain_check
```

If the domain is left blank, rather than returning the validation error from the first `presence` validation, it runs the `:domain_check` function. It seems like it should return immediately when the first validation fails?

Second, when it performs the `:domain_check` function, I am not sure how to check for the `domain` value-- right now I do this:

```
def domain_check

    Rails.logger.debug '###############'
    Rails.logger.debug domain.inspect # prints ""
    Rails.logger.debug domain # prints nothing
    Rails.logger.debug domain.nil? # prints nothing
    Rails.logger.debug '###############'

if domain.nil?
  errors.add(:domain, "Domain is required.")
  return
end
if domain.strip.starts_with?('http://')
    domain.gsub 'http://', ''
elsif domain.strip.starts_with?('https://')
    domain.gsub 'https://', ''
end

uri = 'http://'+domain

response = open(uri).read
# more stuff here
```

The submitted form returns `undefined method "+" for nil:NilClass` on the

```
uri = 'http://'+domain
```

line. I don't understand this, since I checked if the value of `domain` was nil before attempting to create the `uri` string.

This is running under Ruby 2.0.0 -- I believe this code worked properly under Ruby 1.9.3-- is that the cause of this? Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `Rails.logger.debug domain.class` print?

Comment: @UriAgassi-- `Rails.logger.debug domain.class` prints `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that while `nil?` returns false, `empty?` works properly. So instead of using the check for `nil` if you just check if the string is empty it works as expected. Strange, but the blank form value still evaluates to a string, not a `null / nil` value.

```
if domain.empty?
  errors.add(:domain, "Domain is required.")
  return
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [`addressable`](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) gem:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

def domain_check
  address = Addressable::URI.parse(domain)

  if address.nil? || address.host.blank?
    errors.add(:domain, "Domain is required.")
    return
  end

  address.scheme = 'https'
  address.path = nil

  uri = address.to_s

  response = open(uri).read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/http'
def domain_check
  unless self.domain
    errors.add(:domain, "Domain is required")
    return
  else

  case Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(self.domain))
  when Net::HTTPSuccess
    return true
  else
    errors.add(:domain, 'Not a valid domain')
  end
end
```